# Copy value from one node to multiple other nodes using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm just beginning to investigate Firebase Cloud Functions and am struggling to find an example of copying data between database nodes on the server side (fanning out data). More specifically, when a specific user (for example uid "PdXHgkfP3nPxjhstkhX") updates a URL (the dictionary key "link") on the /users node, I'd like to copy that value to all instances of that user's "link" on the /friendsList node. Here's what I have so far. Please let me know if I am approaching this the wrong way.

```
exports.fanOutLink = functions.database.ref('/users/PdXHgkfP3nPxjhstkhX/link').onWrite(event => {

friendsListRef = admin.database().ref('/friendsList');

//if there's no value
if (!event.data.val()){
    //TBD  
}else{
//when there is a value
    let linkURL = event.data.val()
    friendsListRef.once("value", function(snap)){
        snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot)){
           let childKey=childSnapshot.key; 
admin.database().ref('/friendsList/'+childKey+'/PdXHgkfP3nPxjhstkhX/link').set(event.data.val());
        }          
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning a promise, which means that Cloud Functions may terminate your code before it has written to the database, or that it may keep it running (and thus charge you) longer than needed.  I recommend reading more about that [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/06/keep-your-promises-when-using-cloud.html) or watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc).

The simple fix is quite simple in your case:

```
exports.fanOutLink = functions.database.ref('/users/PdXHgkfP3nPxjhstkhX/link').onWrite(event => {
    friendsListRef = admin.database().ref('/friendsList');

    if (!event.data.val()){
        return; // terminate the function  
    }else{
        let linkURL = event.data.val()
        return friendsListRef.once("value", function(snap)){
            var promises = [];
            snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot)){
               let childKey=childSnapshot.key; 
    promises.push(admin.database().ref('/friendsList/'+childKey+'/PdXHgkfP3nPxjhstkhX/link').set(event.data.val()));
            }          
            return Promise.all(promises);
        }
    }
})
```

You'll see that I'm mostly just passing the return value of `once()` and the combined `set()` calls back up (and out of) our function, so that Cloud Functions knows when you're done with it all.

But please study the post, video and other materials thoroughly, because this is quite fundamental to writing Cloud Functions.

If you are new to JavaScript in general, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very clear response. I'll give this a try and accept the answer asap.